# Large text replace array

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, replace

I'm looking for some help when replacing text from when i'm importing an XML file. I want to text-replace some values when importing, so it matches my categories, filter values etc. on my website.

I'm using this function. i wrote it myself with copy-pasting from internet (i'm not a coder) but now i need some help/advice.

```
<?php
// Text replace test function
function my_text_replace($x) {
    for ($y = 0; $y < 2; $y = $y+1) {
        $phrase = $x;
        $old = array("Draaideurkast", "fout1 MRC", "Draaideurkast MRC", "Draaideurkast MRC");
        $new = array("fout1", "fout2", "goed", "fout3");
        $x = str_ireplace($old, $new, $phrase);
        $y = $y+1;
    return $x;
    }
}
?>
```

Code Fix:
What happens is that i do not want a partial match replace, but only the complete value of $x. in the example the output should be 'goed'. it only should replace once when found. (but that is fixed with the for loop i think). the output should be case insensitive.

Advice question:
is this a correct way of replace (large amounts) of texts during an import? you guys know other best practises or plugins (wordpress) or tools..

Thanks for any response!

Harm

Comment: Do you have an example of the input and output as it is now?

Comment: That is one way of doing it. Another is to use preg_replace. But what is the difference between #3 and #4 of old array?

Comment: Doesn't `return` stopping loop? What's the use of `for()` then?

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  difference between #3 and #4 is only for showing purposes.. i want it to only replace something once, not twice. i dont know if return stops the loop. I do know that without the for loop the output is #4

Comment: @Chay22 true.. but then again the loop loops only once as I can see it. `$y < 2` ??

Comment: Yeah, i'm a bit of a code n00b.. Looking forward for a code fix or advice!

Comment: @sebastianForsberg the input as it is now is 'Draaideurkast MRC' (as $x) and the output is fout2. That is because he partially replaces the value, and that is where my problem lies..

Comment: I Still need help with this!